# jQuery - Not sure how to reset max value of array while using .each

Tags: javascript, jquery

Full context available here: http://jsfiddle.net/dweiliu/bcHsy/1/

I currently have 2 sections BOTH of which have 2 tables that are nested inside of their own articles like so:

```
<section>
    <article>
        <h2/>
        <table>...</table>
    </article>
    <article>
        <h2/>
        <table>...</table>
    </article>
</section>
<section>
    <article>
        <h2/>
        <table>...</table>
    </article>
    <article>
        <h2/>
        <table>...</table>
    </article>
</section>
```

I need this behavior to work with 3 articles per section as well etc...

```
$('section').each(function(){
    var heights = [];
    $('article').each(function(){
        heights.push($(this).find('table tr').length);
    });
    maxHeight = Math.max.apply(Math, heights);
    calculatedHeight = maxHeight * 35 + 35;
    $('article').css('height',calculatedHeight);
});
```

I want to be able to go through each section, look at the tables within that section, find the table with the longest ('table tr').length and calculate a height based on that length.

Right now, the code just goes through the entire page and doesn't reset max-value of the array heights once it's done with any given section. I know I am missing something. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: you're not looping through the articles under each section, you're looping through ALL `<article>` tags in the entire document in each iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: Not sure, but shouldn't `$('article')` be relative to the current section being looped? Thus `$(this).find('article').each()`

Comment: @silkfire - That's what I thought but it's wrong. The jQuery selection  ('article') needs to be ('article', this) to add that context.

Comment: @Dave Is there really a difference? To me they're exactly the same.

Comment: @silkfire In my real life example, I have multiple articles with multiple in multiple sections. It made a difference there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your `article`s are within the `section`s. If that's so, you need to select your `article`s within the context of each `section`:

```
$('section').each(function(){
    var heights = [];
    $('article', this).each(function(){
        heights.push($(this).find('table tr').length);
    });
    maxHeight = Math.max.apply(Math, heights);
    calculatedHeight = maxHeight * 35 + 35;
    $('article', this).css('height',calculatedHeight);
});
```

The differences are probably negligible, but you might see if this alternative is faster:

```
$('section').each(function(){
    var max = 0;
    $('article', this).each(function(){
        max = Math.max(max, $(this).find('table tr').length);
    });
    var calculatedHeight = max * 35 + 35;
    $('article', this).css('height',calculatedHeight);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the articles are all nested inside the sections and I knew what it ended up doing. I just didn't know how to select the articles within the context of the sections. The changes in the top block of the code worked for me.

Comment: The changes in the bottom block also worked too. I just needed to fix the reference to maxHeight to use max instead. I'm not sure which is faster.

Comment: Oops, Fixed. Glad I could help. The first option would cause the memory used and array allocations to increase as the number of items increased. The second doesn't. But, like I said, the change might be negligible because you might not have enough items to notice. You'd have to use a profiler to know for sure.